# Gutenberg extend blocks add new class name

Tags: javascript, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to add an extra class name to all the blocks by extending them. Documentation: [Extending Blocks](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/docs/extensibility/extending-blocks.md)

I'm using `blocks.BlockEdit` to modify the edit component. I want to add a custom class name.

So far I have this

```
const withClass = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockListBlock ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        let wrapperProps = props.wrapperProps;
        wrapperProps = {
            ...wrapperProps,
            className: 'my-custom-class',
        };

        return <BlockListBlock { ...props } wrapperProps={ wrapperProps } />;
    };
}, 'withClass' );
```

It's working by adding the custom class to the wrapper but it is overwriting the default block class. Is it possible to append to the current classes without overriding?